# React-Native build android app with incorrect appcompat version, throws error `minCompileSdk (31)` is greater than `compileSdkVersion (android-30)`

Tags: android, react-native

React-Native Android build get failed and throw following error

Error message shows Dependency `androidx.appcompat:appcompat` and it has version `1.4.1` which is different (incorrect) than what set into `app/build.gradle` file `implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0'`

```
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:checkDebugAarMetadata'.
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.CheckAarMetadataWorkAction
   > The minCompileSdk (31) specified in a
     dependency's AAR metadata (META-INF/com/android/build/gradle/aar-metadata.properties)
     is greater than this module's compileSdkVersion (android-30).
     Dependency: androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.4.1.
     AAR metadata file: /Users/<USER>/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/9cbc92e48d81db188c435b3c8306e4e2/transformed/appcompat-1.4.1/META-INF/com/android/build/gradle/aar-metadata.properties.
```

**React-Native Version: `0.67.4`** - not installed into local machine ref: https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup#creating-a-new-application

**Build script ext:**

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        buildToolsVersion = "30.0.2"
        minSdkVersion = 21
        compileSdkVersion = 30
        targetSdkVersion = 30
        ndkVersion = "21.4.7075529"
        supportLibVersion = "28.0.0"
        androidXCore = "1.0.2"
        androidXVersion = "1.+" // Default AndroidX dependency
        androidXAnnotation = "1.1.0"
        androidXBrowser = "1.0.0"
        googleLibVersion = "11.8.0"
        googlePlayServicesVisionVersion = "17.0.2"
        googlePlayServicesVersion = "16.+"
        firebaseVersion = "21.1.0"
        firebaseMessagingVersion = "21.1.0" // version 21.1.0 is mandatory for react-native-push-notifications
        kotlinVersion = "1.5.31" // react-native-navigation requires kotlin version 1.4.x or later
        ext.kotlinVersion = '1.5.31'
        RNNKotlinVersion = kotlinVersion
        RNNKotlinStdlib = "kotlin-stdlib-jdk8"
        kotlin_stdlib_version = '1.1.16'
    }
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenLocal()
        mavenCentral()
        jcenter() // Required by Exoplayer 2.0.2
    }
}
```

Anyone knows how to fix it?

Comment: Have you tried to change compileSdkVersion and targetSdkVersion to 31?

Comment: @NamNgo Yes, after changing compileSdkVersion and targetSdkVersion to 31 build throws `Apps targeting Android 12 and higher are required to specify an explicit value for android:exported` error

Comment: In the cases like this I usually open android directory in Android Studio to check